# How do I get the results from an FTP command run through FtpCommand?

Tags: c#, winapi, ftp, pinvoke

I've wrapped most of wininet with no problems, but now I'm stuck. I am trying to p/invoke [FtpCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384133(VS.85).aspx) from wininet.dll, but every command I run returns "500 syntax error". Even simple commands like dir, or ls. If I connect to the same server with ftp.exe the commands work fine and return expected results.

Here's the method definition:

```
[DllImport("wininet.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError=true)]
extern public static int FtpCommand(
    [In]  IntPtr hConnect,      
    [In]  bool fExpectResponse, 
    [In]  int dwFlags,          
    [In]  string command,
    [In]  IntPtr dwContext,
    [In][Out]  ref int ftpCommand);
```

And the code where I'm calling it:

```
    public string SendCommand(string cmd)
    {
        int result;
        IntPtr dataSocket = new IntPtr();
        switch(cmd)
        {
            case "PASV":
                result = WININET.FtpCommand(_hConnect, false, WININET.FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_ASCII, cmd, IntPtr.Zero, ref dataSocket);
                break;
            default:
                result = WININET.FtpCommand(_hConnect, true, WININET.FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_ASCII, cmd, IntPtr.Zero, ref dataSocket);
                break;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(InternetLastResponseInfo());

        int BUFFER_SIZE = 8192;

        if(result == 0){
            Error();
        }
        else if(dataSocket != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(BUFFER_SIZE);
            int bytesRead = 0;

            do
            {
                result = WININET.InternetReadFile(dataSocket, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, ref bytesRead);
            } while (result == 1 && bytesRead > 1);

            return buffer.ToString();

        }

        return "";
    }
```

Everything else is working, I can download files, upload files and imitate the dir command using FtpFindFirstFile(), but I can't seem to send commands using the above method.

### EDIT

My code for SendCommand has just been SendCommand("DIR") or SendCommand("LS"). After reading one of the answers (can't see who while I'm editing) I changed it to SendCommand("LIST") and that returned successfully.

However, my question was how to read the result, what do I use to read the data returned from the LIST command, so that I can output it in a readable format?

I've updated the SendCommand method to show how I plan on reading the data returned, but I always  get 0 for bytesRead. I've also tried passing the handle received by dataSocket in the FtpCommand call, but the app just exits with no errors if I do that.

### EDIT 2

I'm using InternetReadFile to read data from the handle of the data socket returned in my call to FtpCommand. The method signature for InternetReadFile I am using is this:

```
[DllImport("wininet.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true)]
extern public static int InternetReadFile(
    [In] IntPtr hConnect,
    [In][Out] StringBuilder buffer,
    [In] int buffCount,
    [In][Out] ref int bytesRead);
```

### FINAL EDIT

I released this [code on codeplex](http://ftplib.codeplex.com):

Comment: @Daniel. Yeah, I though about that too. I've changed the function a bit so that based on the command, it may or may not expect the data socket. I can send the PASV command successfully, but I get the same results when I try to read from the dataSocket handle returned from the FtpCommand call.

Comment: Worst case you can use a combination of the PORT command and a TcpListener; it isn't as nice looking, but it definitely works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Why are you getting `500 Syntax error`s?**

Remember that unlike an FTP client (like `ftp.exe`) the actual [FTP protocol](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc959.html) doesn't take commands like `ls`, it takes commands like `LIST` and `NLST`

See the [Raw FTP Command List](http://www.nsftools.com/tips/RawFTP.htm#LIST) or [RFC 959](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc959.html) for a list of commands accepted by FTP

**How do you get the results of a `LIST` or `NLST` command?**

The last parameter to [`FtpCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384133.aspx) is

> A pointer to a handle that is created
>   if a valid data socket is opened. The
>   `fExpectResponse` parameter must be set
>   to `TRUE` for `phFtpCommand` to be filled.

You can use this handle to read out the list with [`InternetReadFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385103.aspx).

**Notes:**

- You might consider using something like [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to see the actual network traffic sent by `ftp.exe` and compare it to what your code is sending
- You might also consider looking into [FtpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.getresponse.aspx); if it meets your needs, it might be easier to use.

Comment: FtpWebRequest does not work for me. I can use it in some cases, but I've had other problems using it.

Comment: When I pass the handle received in dataSocket to InternetReadFile, the app just exits after that call with no errors or exceptions. If I pass the HINTERNET handle, the call works, returns false and the number of bytesRead = 0

Answer (score 1):

The key things that corrected my problem were making sure to send raw FTP commands, rather than commands such as "DIR", pass true (that I expected a data socket), and that the CharSet in the method declaration was CharSet.Ansi. If I replace CharSet.Ansi with CharSet.Auto or CharSet.Unicode, I just get a bunch of gibberish back.

I've update the code samples in the question to reflect what works.